# Bosses randomly despawning in Terraria

Tags: terraria

I'm playing Terraria with my friend, and we're aiming to fight as many bosses as we can. However, even when we are alive and still in the range of the boss, the boss randomly is despawning. This happens even when we are both alive, so my question is why does this happen, and is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Some bosses despawn when they go out of a certain biome, or at a certain time of day

Answer (score 6):

Eye of cthulhu and Skeletron can only spawn during the night. As soon as it turns morning, they fly away.

Brain of Cthulhu, Eater of Worlds and Bee Queen flee the fight as soon as you leave Crimson, corruption or jungle respectively for a period of time.